# Matlab 2012a, static method invocation, not recognizing class outside current folder

Tags: oop, matlab

I have a class `Ellipse` (handle, inherits from other class), that has one static method called `createFromGaussian`. It is located in a remote folder, that I add to Matlab path.
The thing is that, if I try to invoke the static function BEFORE creating any Ellipse object, it fails:

```
>> Ellipse.createFromGaussian(arg1,arg2)
Undefined variable "Ellipse" or class "Ellipse.createFromGaussian".
```

It works if I try any of the following things:

- I change current directory to that in which Ellipse.m file is located
- Working from a remote directory, I create an Ellipse object beforehand:

  ```
  >> Ellipse()
  [C=, axis=[0.0,0.0], angle=0.0]        
  >> Ellipse.createFromGaussian([],2)
  ```

Is this supposed to be this way? The error message sounds weird to me: of course it cannot find variable "Ellipse" or class "Ellipse.createFromGaussian"! It should find "Ellipse" class

Comment: The Matlab oop model is a little odd, and it is evolving. You might have discovered some sort of fringe case. It might be worth making the Mathworks aware of this little oddity. It might be interesting to make the class and its static function part of a package that you import, just to see what happens.

Comment: I just found that if I arrange those classes into a different folder hierarchy, it works. Definitely, it must be some sort of internal error. I will try your suggestion of creating a package (huuuuuge laziness, so much software to rework...).
Be right back with the result :-)

Answer (score 0):

So the Ellipse classdef file, and the function file, are in the same folder called `@Ellipse`, and the PARENT of the `@Ellipse` folder is on the path? That is what Matlab requires for it's system to work.

From the the [ML help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html) : "You must use an @-folder if you want to use more than one file for your class definition. Methods defined in separate files match the file name to the function name and must be declared in the classdef file."

Comment: No, I dont use "@"-folders. I have a single file Ellipse.m containing all the code, Java style.